# How can we detect the lower and upper extreme in boxplot in R?

Tags: r

Suppose that we have the following code that generate random numbers and draw a boxplot:

```
set.seed(1)
a=rchisq(1000,2)
boxplot(a,ylim=c(-5,15))
abline(h=(summary(a))[2]-1.5*IQR(a),col="red")   # Wrong!
abline(h=1.5*IQR(a)+(summary(a))[5],col="red")  # OK! The red line and upper extreme cover each other.
```

How can we draw a line that pass on the lower extreme?

Comment: You may want to take a look at `boxplot.stats(a)`, which gives the calculations underlying the plotting function. Drawing values from there will make anything you draw correspond to the built-in plot.

Answer (score 0):

```
abline(h=summary(a)[1])  # ........
```

OR just:

```
abline(h=min(a) )
```

If as shadow is implying, you don't want extremes in the data but the "extremes of the whiskers" then:

```
abline( h=boxplot.stats$stats[1] )
```

Comment: Or more generally `abline(h=max(min(a), (summary(a))[2]-1.5*IQR(a)),col="red")` and `abline(h=min(max(a), 1.5*IQR(a)+(summary(a))[5]),col="red")`

Answer (score 0):

`boxplot` returns its statistics, so if you save it to a variable when you call it, you can use it later:

```
b <- boxplot(a,ylim=c(-5,15))
abline(h=b$stats[1,],col="red")
abline(h=b$stats[5,],col="red")
```